# add view to another via ref

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How can I add a different view through the refs to the bottom of the view(after `</Text>` and before `</View>`)

for example:

```
addView()
{
What code is needed?
}

render() {
   return (
    <View>
<TouchableOpacity
onPress={() => this.addView() }
>
      <View refs="access">
        <Text>Hello</Text>
        Here it is dynamic
      </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a state value toggle like this:

Edit: To do it to multiple views you can just use an array

```js
state = {displays: [false, false, false, false, false]}

toggleDisplay = (i) => {
  let newDisplays = [...displays]
  newDisplays[i] = !newDisplays[i]
  this.setState({displays: newDisplays}) 
}

render() {
  const { displays } = this.state
  displays.map((display, i) => (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={(i) => this.toggleDisplay(i)}
      >
        <View refs="access">
          <Text>Hello</Text>
          {display && <Text>{'Something Here'}</Text>}
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  ))
}
```

Comment: Thank. I have multiple views with multiple refs, What solution do you recommend?

Comment: @codex I wouldn't use ref if possible. Is the view for addView all the same for the different refs? I would again setup state toggles for the different views. If it is a lot then I would put the strings into the state.

Comment: @codex updated my answer. I would remove the refs and just have the different values in an array in the state. You can modify the state object however you want if you need the strings, but I just used bools to keep it simple.